# Isotope plugin .element resizing and positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

is there any other jQuery Isotope plugin implementor that knows, if it is possible to automatically shrink a currently enlarged .element when a new .element is clicked, and if it is possible to have that currently enlarged .element always displayed top left in the #container div (the other elements can Isotope themselves around as usual after reLayout)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to leverage this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/tests/masonry-corner-stamp.html for stamping the elarged element to the side. If you can't get this to work you might want to look into the "shuffle" functionality and set that elements shuffle property to a value where it always puts it at the top left.

As for the other issue of toggling the enlarged elements you can just remove the class which enlarges the element from the currently enlarged element and put it on the new one using jquery's "removeClass" method.

Comment: Thanks, that got me closer to achieving the desired functionality - adding and removing classes...

Comment: Could you please +1 my answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

With support from the plug-in creator, it can be done rather smoothly via using Isotope's sort function - classing the clicked element while declassing the previously clicked one. I post the website I'm working on, once I have understood it myself ;) It's really amazing how one can customize the workings of this plug-in; worth paying for.